# django-openid-auth django + openid getting blocked by adblock

Tags: django, openid, django-authopenid

I'm using Python's [django-openid-auth](https://bugs.launchpad.net/django-openid-auth) to do OpenID Authentication in my site (by means of an external OpenID provider).

The way it works is you set a link towards local URL (say /openid/login) and that URL handles the login automatically. Problem is, and I'm surprised no one seems to have run into this problem, the view that handles that, creates an invisible form with all the data and submits it automatically to the external authentication page, and that's a big NO-NO for Chrome's adblock, which automatically blocks the request from happening. The end result is that people are now staring at a blank page (because all that view has is the form with hidden fields) and can't actually log in at all.

Is there a workaround for this? For example, being able to embed the form into an existing page and linking the button to the form submit instead of having to go through that blank page? I've been looking at the library files but I wouldn't want to mess with that unless absolutely necessary (also the code is not the clearest).

Thanks in advance!

Bruno